# Check Git status and commit files in PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell

Using Powershell script I need to check the Git status and if there new modified or added files with specific type like ".txt" - I need to add these files and commit them.

Can you help to achieve it?

Firstly I think I need to connect these script to my local git folder
That's what I'm trying and what I've got so far:

```
$ChangedFiles = $(git status --porcelain | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand Count)
if ($ChangedFiles -gt 0)
{
    Write-Output "Found $ChangedFiles changed files"
}
else {
    Write-Output "No changed files"
}
```

and result:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

But I'm trying it in my local git folder.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your "local git folder" the folder in which you usually run `git clone ...`? If so, all the subfolders of that folder will be git repositories, but the folder itself is just a regular folder

Comment: Yep, local git folder it's my usual folder which is cloned. But I've tried to add this script to subfolder as well, in which I usually do some changes and commits. It still the same (

Comment: If you want to look the status of something specific, like `.txt` files as you mentioned, you could do `git status *.txt` or `git status --short *.txt` if you prefer short status. And add with `git add *.txt`

Comment: @Diwas10 Thank you Sir! Can u please advise how to do Git commit, git pull and git push correctly further?

Comment: Commit your changes with `git commit -m "A useful commit message"` and push it over to remote repository using `git push`. Furthermore, you can pull the changes from the remote repository using `git pull`.
 
Tip:
You can get help  for anything using `git --help` or `git commit --help` ... if you find yourself in trouble.